# Wordpress комменты

Tags: wordpress

В wordpress cms я свою дизайн импортировал т.д вот создаю страницу и в нем например пишу что то. Все окей но наверху футера есть такие слова(див или секция коментов):Recents Posts recent comments tags как убрать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это виджеты, скорее всего. Они настраиваются в админ-меню в секции Внешний вид->Виджеты. Просто уберите ненужные из сайдбара.